# Метод определения соприкосновения двух pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли какой нибудь метод соприкосновения 2х пикчерБоксов в c#?

Comment: Что значит "метод соприкосновения" - в смысле обнаружение столкновения?

Comment: именнннннннннно

Comment: Нет конечно. И, как я понял, вы говорите про событие. Вам придется самому писать его.

Comment: Укажите к какой платформе относится вопрос.

Comment: windows forms если я правильно понял вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У структуры `Rectangle` есть метод [`IntersectWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith(v=vs.110).aspx).

У класса `PictureBox` есть несколько свойств, имеющих тип `Rectangle`: `Bounds`, `ClientRectangle`, `DisplayRectangle`. Посмотрите их описание, выберите, какое именно подходит больше всего в вашем случае и используйте.

Например:

```
pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds)
```

Comment: спасибо! жаль что поздно)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, такого события нет. В общем виде это может выглядеть например так:

```
if((pc1.x > pc2.x - pc1.width && pc1.x < pc2.x + pc2.width + pc1.width && pc1.y == pc2.y - pc1.height) ||
   (pc1.y > pc2.y - pc1.height && pc1.y < pc2.y + pc2.height + pc1.height && pc1.x == pc2.x + pc2.width) ||
   ((pc1.x > pc2.x - pc1.width && pc1.x < pc2.x + pc2.width + pc1.width && pc1.y == pc2.y + pc2.height) ||
   (pc1.y > pc2.y - pc1.height && pc1.y < pc2.y + pc2.height + pc1.height && pc1.x == pc2.x - pc2.width)) {
 //соприкосновение произошло
}
```

При этом `pc1` это 1-ый `PictureBox` `pc2` - это 2-ой `PictureBox`. И начало координат `(0;0)` находится в верхнем левом углу.

Comment: Надолго к нам из Индии? :)

Comment: Автор неплохо так покалькулировал :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ваш ответ, несомненно, короче и яснее, но я убеждён на 100%, что метод IntersectsWith внутри работает по тому же принципу. В чём же "индуссость" моего кода? Проще его не сделаешь, разве что яснее.

Comment: Я не говорю, что код плохой. Внутри этот метод примерно так и [реализован](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Rectangle.cs,6033b43c0368f0b4). Просто улыбнуло.